# Bluetooth not supported on android devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

how to show text ((this device not support the Bluetooth )) if this app installed on device not support the Bluetooth
here is my code

```
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

                    // want to add code here to show text ((this device not support    
                    //the Bluetooth )) if this app installed on device not support    
                    // the Bluetooth
```

Comment: You want us to code for you a way to display that info to the user? Wait what?

Comment: You could just have it as an installation requirement. Can't the play store interact with the manifest like that? Also, don't all android phones have bluetooth?

Comment: @keyser not everything Android runs on is a "phone"

Answer (score 1):

If BT is not suppored by the device the code `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` will return `null`. See [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter%28%29). And usefull tutorial also is [there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp).

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
}
```